# EntityFramework code first manually setting PKs which are FKs to other tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am using **EntityFramework** *CodeFirst with existing database*. I am encountering some problems with keys. I have created 
four test tables and models to simulate the situation:

**Party** - *the main container class*.

```
public class Party
{
    // Id is generated at database
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PartyRole> PartyRoles { get; set; }
}
```

**RoleType** - *type to separate some data according to role*.

```
public class RoleType
{
    // This is static library table so need to generate Id
    public short Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

**PartyRole** - *Roles of parties*

```
public class PartyRole
{
    // PartyId and RoleTypeId is composite PK
    public int PartyId { get; set; } // Is FK to Party
    public short RoleTypeId { get; set; } // Is FK to RoleType

    public virtual Party Party { get; set; }
    public virtual RoleType RoleType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Insurer> Insurers { get; set; }
}
```

**Insurer**

```
public class Insurer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // PartyId and RoleTypeId is composite FK to PartyRole
    public int PartyId { get; set; }
    public short RoleTypeId { get; set; }

    // Other properties

    public virtual PartyRole PartyRole { get; set; }
}
```

I have not included mapping details for simplicity. Mapping details are correct and written using Fluent API.
When I try to manually set PKs of PartyRole and insert it this values are not reflected at Insurer:

```
using (MyTestContext testContext = new MyTestContext())
{
    Insurer insurer = new Insurer();

    PartyRole partyRole = new PartyRole()
    {
        PartyId = 1, // Party with this Id already exist
        RoleTypeId = 1, // RoleType with this id already exist
        Insurers = new List<Insurer>() { insurer }
    };

    testContext.Set<PartyRole>.Add(partyRole);
    testContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

When I execute above code generates following sql statements:

```
insert into "PARTY_ROLES"
            ("ID",
             "ROLE_TYPE_ID")
values      (1 /* :p0 */,
             1 /* :p1 */);

insert into "INSURERS"(
    "PARTY_ID",
     "ROLE_TYPE_ID")
values (
    0 /* :p0 */,
     0 /* :p1 */);
```

My question is why EF sends *(0, 0)* to insert into INSURERS where they should be *(1, 1)*?

If *PartyId* and *RoleTypeId* were not **FKs** in *PartyRole* model it would send *(1, 1)*.

Comment: I guess `Insurer.Id` is an identity column?

Comment: Yes it is an identity column @GertArnold

Comment: Could you also simulate what happens in `PartyRole`'s constructor (if anything)?

Comment: It has default constructor, nothing special there @GertArnold

Answer (score 0):

EF couldn't guess this. You can always manually set keys for insurer:

```
Insurer insurer = new Insurer()
{
    PartyId = 1,
    RoleTypeId = 1
};
...
testContext.SaveChanges();
```